# List environment and bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, lists

I am using the list environment to control the margins when I print the bibiography, but the numbers disappear. How could this problem be solved?

I use the code

```
\begin{list}{}{
\leftmargin=1.52cm
\rightmargin=0cm
}\smallskip\item[]%
%-- Text -----
\printbibliography
%--------------
\end{list}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're using the `biblatex` package. If so, why aren't you using `biblatex`'s own machinery to control the appearance of the formatted bibliography? Aside: The LaTeX `list` environment is a very low-level tool; if you don't know exactly what you're doing when setting up a `list` environment, it's probably a good idea *not* to use this tool...

Comment: I'm using a general environment with the tcolorbox package, obviously I can make a suitable change to the bibliography, but the question is about the list environment , and I ask the question because I don't really know this environment well.

Comment: In that case, you may want to edit your posting to (a) remove the `bibliographies` tag and (b) emphasize that you're interested purely in how to handle the `list` environment.

Comment: Everything works perfectly for this environment with expandable boxes, the only problem is the interaction of the list environment with the bibliography.

Comment: your claim is vague (not correct). `\bibliography` is some sort of list, however it use `\bibitem`, but ordinary list `\item` (simplified explanation). consequently in list all ``\bibliography`` is one `item` in it ...

Comment: What Zarco says makes sense, that's why it only appears[1].  The purpose of using list is to have an expandable environment and control the margins. Is there any way then to make list see the bibliography as a sublist, as when we nest in the enumerate environment?